# Data Lineage/Traceability in Pipelines

Tags: preprocessing, feature-construction, pipelines

I want to collect information about: 1) from which single data signals a feature is composed in a ML pipeline and 2) what data preprocessing operations are/were executed on a data signal.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of information gathering and can recommend a tool or API for it? (eg. in Apache Airflow, Luigi, RapidMiner or KNIME)

May I just missed the right term that describes this kind of meta-data?